# How to amplify amplitudes above some threshold, given additional information about the state

Tags: quantum-state, quantum-algorithms, amplitude-amplification

Given a quantum state $\left|\Psi\right> = \sum_{i=0}^{2^n-1} \alpha_i\left|i \right>$, for which I know that the *probabilities* ($|\alpha_i|^2$) follow a sine/cosine like distribution as in the following picture.
[image]

It is important to note that I do not know for *which* basis states the probability is maximal or minimal, I just know that the distribution follows such a sine/cosine wave.

Now, how can I amplify those probabilities that are above some threshold $\tau$?
I just need to "spike" the distribution a little more.
I suspect I can do amplitude estimation to write the amplitudes in an ancilla register, mark those states that are above the threshold $\tau$ and then do amplitude amplification.
This works for any state $\left|\Psi\right>$, but is there a simpler, more efficient algorithm to spike the probabilities, given that I know how the state looks like?